# Erro ao ocultar <div> por seleção de <option> em formulário com javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma função em javascript com jquery que oculta divs quando uma option é selecionada. Funciona quase perfeitamente, mas quando você volta para uma option anterior, depois de ter escolhido uma option que abre div, a div que foi aberta antes não desaparece mais (a não ser que escolha uma das options que abre outra div, daí ele troca).

```
$(function(){
    $("#motde").change(function(){
          if($(this).val()=='mostrard'){
              $('#justcausa').show();
              $('#rescind').hide();
          }
          if ($ (this).val()=='mostrarc'){
              $ ('#rescind').show();
              $('#justcausa').hide();
          }
          if ($ (this).val()=='nada') {
              $ ('rescind').hide();
              $ ('justcausa').hide();
          }
     });
});
```

Coloquei no jsfiddle pra facilitar o entendimento: https://jsfiddle.net/gustavox/u9avs55f/3/

O que acontece é que se vc seleciona as opções 2 ou 3, ele abre e altera certinho as divs, mas se vc escolhe outra opção depois (muda de opção, pra uma que não abre div), ele não faz as divs desaparecerem. Para melhor entendimento, selecione a option 2, e depois a 4. A div aberta por causa da option 2 devia desparecer, só que isso não acontece.

Por quê?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linha 12 e 13 faltando # para indica id, altere:

```
 $ ('rescind').hide();
 $ ('justcausa').hide();
```

para:

```
 $ ('#rescind').hide();
 $ ('#justcausa').hide();
```

Comment: OMG! Close topic, ban op! :) Valeu!